# How does "multi-argument" functional composition work (e.g. fmap . fmap)?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, function-composition

When we have the expression:

```
(fmap . fmap) function nested_functor
```

I would expect it to translate to something like

```
fmap (fmap function nested_functor)
```

Though it surprisingly seems to behave as

```
fmap (fmap function) nested_functor
```

Why?

Comment: All functions are single-argument, i.e. `a->b->c` is the same as `a->(b->c)`. Build from here.

Comment: ... and so `f x y` is the same as `(f x) y`. (`f :: a->(b->c)`, `x :: a`, `y :: b`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, just look at the definition of `(.)`:

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

So,

```
(fmap . fmap) function = fmap (fmap function)
```

Adding an additional argument at the end doesn't really change the equation -- just makes it more specific.

```
(fmap . fmap) function nested_functor = fmap (fmap function) nested_functor
```

(N.B. function application is left associative, so `f x y` means `(f x) y`.)

Comment: Thank you! My confusion was due to thinking through this as if function application would be right associative, and the mess was due to that (->) associating to the right in the type signatures... I am now finding it funny that functional application in type declarations has a different associativity than in the expressions themselves.

Comment: @PedroMorteRolo It is sort of symmetrical that way. With it set like it is, you can have no parentheses in an application of `fn` to 'two' arguments as `fn x y` and no parentheses in the corresponding type signature for `fn :: Int -> Int -> Bool` (for example). If they associated in the same way (regardless of which way that is), one of those two things would need parens and the other wouldn't.